# How do I write a generic C++ function to parse xml into structs?

Tags: c++, xml, templates, boost

I have a collection of xml data files representing objects of interest in images (rectangles, points, labelled faces, etc.) that I want to parse to produce vectors of structs. The files are manually created (and so are not just the result of serialising some C++ objects) and are of the following form:

```
<root>
<image filename=whatever>
<object>
  <x>1</x>
  <y>2</y>
</object>
<object>
  <x>3</x>
  <y>4</y>
</object>
</image>
<image filename=something>
 ...
</image>
</root>
```

So a collection of images, each of which contains a collection of object children, each of which has children giving the data relevant to that object. The structure of this data varies between files, e.g. in one file each object might just have an x and a y and in another each object might contain ints x1, y1, x2, y2 and a double z.

I want to parse such a file to produce a vector of Objects, where Object is a struct, in this case of the form struct Object { int x; int y; }.

For different choices of Object, I've currently got separate functions that use rapidxml to parse the xml in identical ways, except for which fields they extract.

I'd like to write a templated function so that you can merely specify the elements of a struct in some way and have the function return a vector of the appropriate structs. i.e. The user should specify a list of pairs ("x1", int), ("x2", int), etc. and have the rest of the work be done automatically.

I'm sure there must be a nice boost solution to this problem that avoids having to use XML schema. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to use `libxml++`?

Comment: I haven't, but the documentation suggests that it's just a basic XML parser and doesn't solve my problem. Have I missed something?

Comment: Since C++ does not have reflection, you essentially can't do what you want without a huge amount of code that simulates reflection. It is better to figure out all concrete types that you need and then use code generation to manage it.

Comment: Without knowing more details, I can't say anything more concrete, but you might be able to adapt your structs to boost::fusion lists (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html), and then automatically fill the lists with data from the XML. Using variadic templates might be difficult to use, since you don't know the order in which the data is coming..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [Boost Property Tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/property_tree.html#boost_propertytree.intro).

It allows you to write your own load/save functions to map XML (or INI or JSON) data onto your own structures. See the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html).

It even uses RapidXML which you're already using.

**Edit:**

You could try something like

```
template<typename T>
struct Field
{
    typedef T type;
    std::string name;
};

template<typename... Fields>
std::tuple<typename Fields::type...>
load(const Data& data, Fields... f)
{
    return std::make_tuple( data.get<typename Fields::type>(f.name)... );
}
```

Where `Data` is some source of the input data, like a `boost::ptree`, and you'd use that function like this:

```
load(d, Field<int>{"x1"}, Field<int>{"x2"} );
```

Then you'd just need each data type to be constructible from a tuple of the right types.

Comment: That gives a nicer interface for XML parsing, but doesn't appear to solve my issue; you'd still need a separate function for each choice of data object wouldn't you?

Comment: Betcha that's easier and quicker than writing the generic version.

Comment: I've updated the answer with something that might help, but you'll always need to do more than just `("x1", int), ("x2", int)` because you need to map those to `Object::x1` and `Object::x2` which can't be done without additional input (even if it's just including `&Object::x1` alongside `"x1"` and `int`) ... unless you get rid of your object types entirely and just use tuples to hold the data

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it would work. Sadly, I can't use C++11 features. I guess I could replace the variadic template with something that takes a typelist. You're right that a bit of code duplication would be a lot easier and quicker, but I was interested in how this would be done generically.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write an XML schema for your XML file, there are tools that generate an C++-API from the schema. Keyword is "C++ XML schema binding".

I have used the [XSD compiler](https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) but there are other similar tools out there...